# How to convert string column to date in ssas tabular model

Tags: sql-server, dax, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I have created two calculated columns to convert date format as DD-MMM-YYYY(Ex:- 01-Jan-2018).

If I access cube data in excel those columns converting as string type.

I would like to convert them as date type.

Below is the function which I have used in calculated columns

```
 =FORMAT(DATA_EXTRACT[START_DATE],"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Comment: What was the data format in [START_DATE]?

Comment: @RADO In model desing it has text format.

Comment: 01-11-2020 00:00:00 this is actual format in column.

Comment: 01-Nov-2020 this is calculated column result.

Comment: If I access data into excel it has been showing as string type.

Comment: Just to confirm, [START_DATE] column has type "text" in your data model? I am trying to make sure it's really a text, not a datetime.

Comment: Yes, by default it has picked text type because of formula.

Comment: No I have not used.

Comment: How do I specify DD-MMM-YYYY format in datevalue.

Comment: I want to format from 01-11-2020 00:00:00 to 01-Jan-2020.

Comment: Well, you are trying to solve a wrong problem. Don't confuse **data type** with **presentation format**. Data type you need in your data model is Date. Then, in Excel, you can format it in any way you want.

Comment: Actual column data type is date.here, I don't have an issue.Actually I am unable to change presentation format in excel so that's the reason I have created calculated column to bring up '01-Jan-2020' format in excel.

Comment: In calculated column data type showing as text.

Comment: it's general data format and data type is date.

Comment: START_DATE= 09/01/2002